# Minimum permissions to Facebook-login to Parse.com

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

By following this document:
https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views
one can see how to put a Facebook login button to connect to Parse.com.
It seems that by default we are asking for more permissions than my needs though.

I only want the minimum so that the user can login into Parse.com conveniently with the Facebook button.
I do not need to know about the user’s friend or anything else.
What is the way to customize the code in order to get the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following to specify permission:

```
loginViewController.facebookPermissions = @[ @"user_about_me" ];
```

To see a full list of the Facebook permission you can visit:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1
```

The default permission is `public_profile` and it includes:

```
id, name, first_name, last_name, link, gender, locale, age_range
```